# Spyder 4.1 3 change from python 3 to python 2

Tags: python-2.7, spyder

I tried wath people suggested, but it doesn't work, I think because of the difference between spyder 3 and spyder 4. When I tried this in the console:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7  #for version 2.7
activate py27,
```

I got the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-1-bf66fb85464f>", line 1
    conda create -n py27 python=2.7  #for version 2.7
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I change it, because I need python 2.7 for school

Comment: "in the console" - which console, exactly? This command is supposed to be executed from the shell, not Python

Comment: console 1/A this is a iPython console, where do I find the shell?

Comment: the shell is what's inside the terminal when you first open it. Open a new terminal window, and the shell will be there.